# How to know if app user is offline android app?

Tags: java, php, android, mqtt

Currently i am developing a cab booking app.
Now i am working on driver app.
Now my task is, i want to make him offline and online when ever internet get disconnected orconnected .

In my database i have a column is_online which value goes to 1 when he online and 0 when he is offline.

well now i know how to make him online but how to make him offline? if internet got disconnected ! how can i update value in db . it remain 1
never goes to 0;

Current i am using Broadcast Receiver that notify me  when internet get disconnected or connected.

```
<?PHP
require_once 'include/DB_Settings_Functions.php';
$db = new DB_Functions();

// json response array
$response = array("error" => FALSE);

if(isset($_POST['driver_id'])&&isset($_POST['status']))
{  
$driver_id= $_POST['driver_id'];
$status= $_POST['status'];  




     $user = $db->makeOnline($driver_id,$status);





        }



?>
```

I heard that it can be solved by using mqtt any working example ? can anyone help me? i am using local host wamp server.

Edit:
In simple words i want to send value in server before connection goes down any idea how it can be done using mqtt ?

Comment: can you show the broadcast receiver class? I know it's called everytime there is a change on network but i don't know if you could send a value before the network goes down

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Apparently you are able to set `status = 1` on your database when the user has an internet connection. So just set it to 0 when he loses the internet connection. Maybe you are always passing 1 as `$status` by mistake?

Comment: i also want to how can i send a value before connection goes down

Comment: @simon nope i passing value 1 from device

Comment: But you should pass 0 when the user lost the connection.

Comment: @simon but how before connection goes down? can you give example using mqtt protocol?

Comment: What do you mean with _before_? How should Android know that the connection is going to be dropped? I have never used mqtt so I can't help on this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fire a request on every minutes from mobile app and stored it's date and time into data base. if user is online that means last access time will update every minutes in database and if user is offline then it's time last access time will not update in data base so you just need to fire a sql query for get offline user that have last access time is grater then 2 minus.

Comment: nice solution but i think it will drain more battery?  any solution by using mqtt?

Comment: i don't thing it will drain more battery because your application only fire a request on server it's not perform any other activity with that. and request will fire when user is online in app not with offline app.

Answer (score 1):

MQTT has a function called the Last Will and Testament (LWT), this is a messages that is published by the broker when the client connection times out.

This means that the client can publish a retained message to a unique topic when it comes online (e.g. publish 1 to /status). It can then set up a LWT to publish 0 to the same topic if the connection drops. It should also manually publish 0 before manually closing the connection as LWT only fires if the connection drop unexpectantly.

You can adjust the time out value to suit your needs.

Comment: thanks for answering can you give me give one working example both client side and server side?

Comment: No, not without seeing your entire code base. The Paho android client (https://eclipse.org/paho/clients/android/) has the ability to set a LWT and backend is just normal MQTT message handling and will depend on how you choose to implement that